# Selecting jQuery tabs from another DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I am trying to position links to jQuery Tabs under the tab content, with the tabs navigation in its own DIV (for styling purposes). Here is my markup:

```
    <div id="fpTabs">
  <div id="fpTab-1">
    <p>This is the first tab</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fpTab-2">
    <p>This is the second tab...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fpTab-3">
    <p>This is the third tab.. </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="fpTabs-nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#fpTab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fpTab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fpTab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

How would I go about activating Tabs using the ul in #fpTabs-nav for navigation?

Thanks!

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select   basically it's used as a event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to select a specific tab programmatically

```
var $tabs = $("#fpTabs").tabs();
$tabs.tabs('select',1); // will select the 2nd tab, index is 0-based
```

So it would be something like:

```
$("#fpTabs-nav ul li").click(function() {
   $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).index());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.. BUT only if there is also a tabs nav ul in the same DIV as the tab DIVs. Obviously I can just hide this with CSS but it's a bit redundant. Any way to avoid needing two sets of navs? (this is why my similar attempts failed, apparently)

Comment: You could grab the entire `<ul>` from the `#fpTabs` divs and place it into the `#fpTabs-nav` div, like: http://jsfiddle.net/bjorn/8qPad/9/. Might not be optimal, but I don't think you can even create tabs through `$.tabs` without, well, tabs ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to do some more investigating but this works just fine for now. Cheers :)